# Is there an issue using external portable USB drives with Windows and Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, format, drive

I had errors with my Western Digital My Passport Ultra 2TB external portable USB disk drive. So I re-formatted it (NTFS) under Windows 10. I then took the formatted drive and hooked it up to my Dell XPS Developer Edition laptop running Ubuntu 14.04. I was able to successfully copy multiple directories of files (text files, images, videos, word processor documents) to the drive. However, after copying the files, neither of my Windows 10 laptops can read the **drive** - including the one that formatted it originally. But the drive is still readable by the Ubuntu machine.

Is is possible to write to an external USB drive in Ubuntu and read it in Windows 10?

Comment: You should make it more clear what files did you copy and can you access the USB Drive under Windows at all or it's only files that cannot be read?

Comment: @user68186 I pushed the up- arrow/line icon in the Fiiles application which appears to unmount the drive.